# Data exchange between two users using Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am not sure how is this process called. Say I am a user of the app and I want to know if there is a message for me (*or a status change that I need to know about*), I am not sure if this is the best way but I am trying to do it like this:

```
Firebase Structure

Users   >  User A  >   Status = "No messages"
```

Each user has a node `Status` as you can see above.
When user A sends a message to user B, user A changes user B's `Status` node.

User B, that had been listening to his own `Status` node, is now aware that there is something new and can go read the message.

Is this possible and safe making use of Firebase only?

Answer (score 3):

On a simpler note, and more often used scenario similar to yours is like a Chat Application. User A sends a message to User B, User B then receives a notification from Firebase.

From what you have described, you intend to have a listener in place for the `Status` node, and inform the user whenever it changes. This seems okay, but from what was advised to me before, keeping the listener active tends to have a corresponding active socket on Android, which adds to battery consumption.

What I suggest you make use of is [firebase-cloud-messaging](/questions/tagged/firebase-cloud-messaging):

> [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) is a component of the [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) suite of tools for cross-platform application development.
>
> - **Send unlimited** upstream/**downstream messages**
> - **Send messages to individual devices** or a user segment
> - Handle all aspects of queueing and delivery
> - **Optimize for battery efficiency**
>
> Using FCM, you can **notify a client app that new email or other data is available to sync**. You can send notifications to drive user reengagement and retention. For use cases such as instant messaging, a message can transfer a payload of up to 4KB to a client app.

I think this [Firebase Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/#0) for a Chat App might also be helpful.