# Can i use firebase cloud messaging to create an android chat application to be used at large scale

Tags: android, chat, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am a beginner in android application development,therefore i dont know the cons of firebase cloud messaging.So,can i use fcm for chat application which can handle multiple users at a time

Comment: Yes, theoretically you can.
No, if it's by abusing the push notification of the user instead of using socket.
Also, I'd suggest googling that - it's a really common question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Data exchange between two users using Firebase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39335282/data-exchange-between-two-users-using-firebase)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FCM can be a valid part of a chat application, but it will only be one piece of the puzzle. You also need a server component for a complete solution.

Two advantages of FCM over other approaches for messaging:

1. No need to create an additional connection for the most part (battery, data, & performance advantage) if you use XMPP as your protocol for upstream and downstream messaging. An XMPP FCM client will reuse the device's single persistent connection to FCM servers.
2. Ability to have (high-priority) messages trigger a notification even in Doze mode to ensure instant user notification.

There are alternative technologies available that you might consider, but for a beginner in Android development FCM may be one of the better approaches if you know your way around a server.